# how to display image to popup window

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fileapi

I have read an image in memory using the [readAsdataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29) javascript function. Now I need to display this image in a popup window which is opened when a button is clicked in an existing page.

How can I do that? Is there any way in which I can read the image from memory and then display it in the new popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Check this - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files

seems it has example that you need:

```
<style>
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

just replace that div with popup that you want